# MySQL version to be used on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: installation, 10.04, mysql

I've a production server and a test server both having Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

When I installed MySQL on test server, I just run

`apt-get install mysql-server`

and **5.1.62-0ubuntu0.10.04.1** got installed

When I installed MySQL on production server server,

I first run `apt-get dist-upgrade`

and then run `apt-get install mysql-server`

and **5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10** got installed.

The version of Ubuntu on the production server is 10.04.2 LTS,  and the MysQL server installed is `5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10`.

What does this mean?

The MySQL version is intended to run with Ubuntu 12.10?

Comment: Sure, your helped, I waited just to see what others have to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- On Ubuntu 10.04.4, the following `mysql-server` packages are shown as available (`apt-cache showpkg mysql-server`):

  ```
  5.1.63-0ubuntu0.10.04.1
  5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10 
  5.1.41-3ubuntu12.7 
  5.1.41-3ubuntu12
  ```
- As the version numbers show, the latest is 5.1.63; the 5.1.41-3*ubuntu12.10* has **nothing** to do with Ubuntu 12.10, but is just a numbering coincidence (notice the -12.7 and -12 versions prior to that).
- Thus, an up-to-date 10.04.4 system should be running mysql-server 5.1.63. Your production server needs to be updated to 10.04.4, and then an `upgrade` will install 5.1.63.

  - Check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and make sure that the `lucid-updates` and `lucid-security` repositories are included; then run `sudo apt-get update` before `dist-upgrade` or `upgrade`

---

- The current *mysql-server* versions available for 12.04 LTS are:

  ```
  5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  5.5.22-0ubuntu1
  ```
- And for the upcoming 12.10 Quantal:

  ```
  5.5.25-0ubuntu2
  ```

Answer (score 0):

For any kind of production or test server I would suggest getting MySQL 5.5 binaries from Oracle or MariaDB. They are easy to install and maintain. Version 5.5 bought massive improvements, including performance and the push to make an ACID compliant release with InnoDB being the default storage engine (it still however requires editing the MySQL config file to make sure InnoDB is following *all* the ACID requirements).

More info here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-acid.html